# Why do i pay for my serverless aurora database v2 when not using it?

Tags: aws-aurora-serverless

I have paid about fourty dollars for aurora database `serverless`, without using it. Though to pay for `aws` services, i wonder how this is possible, when i do not use the database myself at all?

Does **serverless** not mean, that i just pay for usage?

Comment: "serverless" _really_ means "runs-on-a-server-you-dont-own".

Comment: @Dai this is gold!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do I pay for my serverless aurora database v2 when not using it?

Because you *are* using it - even if you aren't *actively* using it to service requests and queries, you're still paying for it to be *operationally available*. Think of it as being like an AWS VM: you can pay for it by-the-minute (or second?) but you have to pay for it so-long as it's running, and not only for the times when you have an active shell connection in your terminal.

[AWS's documentation says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.how-it-works.html) that there is a **minimum** purchase of "0.5 ACUs" of Aurora V2 capacity, which is charged to your account for every *second* it is running:

> Each ACU is a combination of approximately 2 gibibytes (GiB) of memory, corresponding CPU, and networking.
>
> [...]
>
> At any moment in time, each Aurora Serverless v2 DB writer or reader has a capacity. The capacity is represented as a floating-point number representing ACUs. The capacity increases or decreases whenever the writer or reader scales. This value is measured every second.
>
> [...]
> The **smallest Aurora Serverless v2 capacity that you can define is 0.5 ACUs**.